# Custom Label To PDF

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdf-generation

I have the following requirement. I will have to generate a custom label having the user info to PDF.

This is a multi line label and each line has a different text format and different font size (please see the attached - below).

[image: example]

Image URL: http://www34.zippyshare.com/v/84819344/file.html (as stack over flow doesnt let me add images)

Can I achieve something like that and how ?

Im using .net framework 3.5 and Visual Studio 2010 and C#. Please provide a sample in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) library. It will do what you need, and it's not especially complex. It's also free (AGPL license) for open source software.